# How to set multi select value from array object in yii2 while updating

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have table which have multiple reference to ohter tables like

```
user
id         name         email
categories
id         title
user_categories
user_id    category_id
```

Here a user will have multiple category associated with him/her

I am able to save these successfully with new records like following

**View File:**

```
echo $form->field($package_categories, 'category_id')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(
StudyMaterialCategories::find()->all(), 'id', 'title'), 
['multiple' => true]
);
```

**Save New record:**

```
$model = new Packages();
$package_categories = new PackageCategories();
$request = Yii::$app->request;
if ($request->isPost) {
    $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $post = $request->post();
        $model->load($post);
        $model->save();
        foreach ($post['PackageCategories']['category_id'] as $key => $value) {
            $package_categories = new PackageCategories();
            $package_categories->category_id = $value;
            $package_categories->package_id = $model->id;
            $package_categories->save();
        }
        $transaction->commit();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $transaction->rolback();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash("error", $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Till now It's running successfully.

But I'm stuck when going to update the table. The problem part is dropdown list. How to set multiple selected option as per database if I'm coming with array of object.
Have a look on the following code

```
$package_categories = PackageCategories::find()
->where('package_id=:package_id', ['package_id' => $id])->all();
if (count($package_categories) < 1) {
    $package_categories = new PackageCategories();
}
$request = Yii::$app->request;
if ($request->isPost) {
    $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $post = $request->post();
        $model->load($post);
        $model->save();
        $package_categories = new PackageCategories();
        $package_categories->deleteAll(
            "package_id=:package_id", 
            [':package_id' => $model->id]
        );
        foreach ($post['PackageCategories']['category_id'] as $key => $value) {
            $package_categories = new PackageCategories();
            $package_categories->category_id = $value;
            $package_categories->package_id = $model->id;
            $package_categories->save();
        }
        $transaction->commit();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $transaction->rolback();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash("error", $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

if I try to get first object of the array `$package_categories` of only able to set selected one option

Comment: to show multiple items selected inside a multi-select you just need to set the values as array to the model field that is used to show the multiple select.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example code of a model class `Permit` which has a `many to many` relationship with `Activity` through `PermitActivity` (pivot table model).

**Model Class Activity**

```
public class Permit extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public $activities_ids;
    ...
    public function rules() {
        return [
            ...
            [['activities_ids'], 'safe'],
            ...
        ];
    }
    ...
    // Method called after record is saved, be it insert or update.
    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
        // If this is not a new record, unlink all records related through relationship 'activities'
        if(!$this->isNewRecord) {
            // We unlink all related records from the 'activities' relationship.
            $this->unlinkAll('activities', true);
            // NOTE: because this is a many to many relationship, we send 'true' as second parameter
            // so the records in the pivot table are deleted. However on a one to many relationship
            // if we send true, this method will delete the records on the related table. Because of this,
            // send false on one to many relationships if you don't want the related records deleted.
        }

        foreach($this->activities_ids as $activity_id) {
            // Find and link every model from the array of ids we got from the user.
            $activity = Activity::findOne($activity_id);
            $this->link('activities', $activity);
        }

        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }
    ...
    // Declare relationship with Activity through the pivot table permitActivity
    public function getActivities(){
        return $this->hasMany(Activitiy::className(), ['id' => 'activity_id'])
            ->viaTable('permitActivity',['permit_id' => 'id']);
    }
    ...
    public function afterFind(){
        parent::afterFind();
        $this->activities_id = ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->activities, 'id');
    }
}
```

This way the model class is the one responsible for creating and updating the relationship using the pivot table.

The most important thing is to have the relationship method declared correctly.

**Edit**

This is an example of the view using [`kartikv\widgets\Select2`](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2). I don't really know if dropDownList supports multiple select, however Select2 has so many useful features i usually use it over other options.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'activities')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => '...'
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: My question is how do I will set multiple item selected in view

Comment: In my example, the multiple items field is `activities_ids`

Comment: Give me an example to show on view like $form->field($modal_obj, 'attribute_name')->dropdownlist($items, ['multiple'=>true])

Comment: Added example with Select2 widget by Krajee

Comment: I think $data variable in the widget is array, but my question is how do I will  set two options as selected when we are in update form?

Comment: yea, `$data` is an associative array, with `'value' => 'Option Name'`. Just by setting `'multiple' => true,` the widget will allow to choose many options, which will be sent through post as an array with the values selected. In the model in the `afterSave` method the model takes these values and links them to the model, creating the relationship with the elements from the other table.

Comment: If you see my question seriously, you'll get there that it's already being used, and I'm capable to select multiple. My question how to set selected multiple when rendering form when I click on edit button.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Added `afterFind` code. There you find the ids of the related records and save them on the attribute that you use for the form.